# Can I access the spare floats in a mat3 in GLSL?

Tags: glsl

I'm using a mat3 uniform in a GLSL shader.

```c
layout (std140)
struct UNI {
    mat3 mat;
} u;
```

A mat3 is stored as 3 rows of vec4 in GLSL so that means there's 3 unused floats in there.

Is there any way to access those floats? I want to to pack some more data in there.

nb. I tried using `u.mat[0][3]` but it says "array index out of bounds" when I compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things here:

1. the actual memory layout of the data
2. the API that GLSL provides you to access the data

When you are using Uniform Buffer Objects (UBO) to back the storage of the `mat3` and are using the `std140` layout, then yes, a `mat3` is layed out in exactly the same way as 3 `vec4` values. So, essentially, under `std140` layout there is no difference in the memory layout between a `mat3x4` (three columns each with 4 rows/elements) and a `mat3` or `mat3x3`.

However, you cannot *access* the fourth row of each column when using a `mat3` as the API type in the GLSL shader.

What you *could* do instead is simply use the `mat3x4` type, which would give you access to the fourth row. And when you need a `mat3` you can cast it with `mat3(theMat3x4Value)`.

Comment: I tried the typecast the other way around to avoid rewriting my shaders, ie 'mat3x4 t = mat3x4(u.mat); w = t[0].w;'. It seems to work.

Comment: @httpdigest std140 is _very_ defined behaviour. That's the whole point of using it.